# Examine uniform and pointwise convergence of the function series $\sum_{n=n_{0}}^{+\infty}f_n$

Tags: real-analysis

> Examine uniform and pointwise convergence of the function series $\sum_{n=n_{0}}^{+\infty}f_n$ for: $$f_n: [-100,100]\rightarrow \mathbb R$$ $$f_n=\frac{1}{n} \sin (\frac{x}{n})$$

**My try:**

I want to use the fact that if series $\sum_{n=n_{0}}^{+\infty}||f_n||$ is convergent then function series $\sum_{n=n_{0}}^{+\infty}f_n$ is uniformly convergent: $$||f_n||=||\frac{1}{n}\sin (\frac{x}{n})||=sup_{x\in[-100,100]}(\frac{1}{n}|\sin (\frac{x}{n})|)=\frac{1}{n}sup_{x\in[-100,100]}(|\sin (\frac{x}{n})|)$$Then we know that $x\ge \sin x$. However in this task I have absolute value and I don't know if I can use it. If yes I have: $$0\le||f_n||\le\frac{1}{n}sup_{x\in[-100,100]}(|\frac{x}{n}|)=\frac{100}{n^2}$$So from direct comparison test series $\sum_{n=n_{0}}^{+\infty}||f_n||$ is convergent so function series $\sum_{n=n_{0}}^{+\infty}f_n$ is uniform and pointwise convergence.
Can you judge if I have correctly used the fact about $x\ge \sin x$?

Comment: $x \geq \sin\, x$is not true for negative numbers so you have to use the fact that $|x| \geq |\sin\, x|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because $|x| \geq |\sin(x)|$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

To see this:

True for all positive $x$.

For negative $x$, $x=-y, y>0$, $|\sin(-y)| = |-\sin(y)| = |\sin(y)| \leq |-y| = |y|$